# Nightmarejs screenshot doesn't clip at the bottom of long pages

Tags: node.js, screenshot, electron

I am trying to make a screenshot at the bottom of the long page (e.g. http://www.taoism.net/ttc/complete.htm) like so:

```
Nightmare({ show: false })
    .viewport(1024, 30000)
    .goto('http://www.taoism.net/ttc/complete.htm')
    .wait()
    .screenshot(sImagePath, {
        x      : 0,
        y      : 27711,
        width  : 1024,
        height : 133
    });
```

Screenshot file size is 0 bytes.
Tested with different `y` values, it works until ~8000px.
Tried using `.scrollTo`, it did not help.

Does anybody know a workaround?

P.S. Nightmarejs wraps around electron browser.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you've looking for https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/328#issuecomment-159311982

Basically you dynamically adjust the viewport dimensions based on the content to grab size.